# Magento 2.4.3 - Problem with agreements checkbox and store credit

Tags: checkout, magento2.4

4.3, in our checkout form, we have the agreements checkbox (in checkout-agreements.html file). When a customer makes a purchase and arrives at the checkout, and checks the conditions box, and if "Store Credit" applies at this point, the conditions box is unchecked again and you have to check it again.

What and how can I do so that I only have to mark it once and it is not unmarked when adding or removing the store credit?

Thank you!

**[Update]**

Default agreements input:

`<input type="checkbox" class="required-entry" data-bind="attr: { 'id': $parent.getCheckboxId($parentContext, agreementId), 'name': 'agreement[' + agreementId + ']', 'value': agreementId }" id="agreement_credit_card_5" name="agreement[5]" value="5">`

After applying store credit:

`<input type="checkbox" class="required-entry" data-bind="attr: { 'id': $parent.getCheckboxId($parentContext, agreementId), 'name': 'agreement[' + agreementId + ']', 'value': agreementId }" id="agreement_free_5" name="agreement[5]" value="5">`

Answer (score 0):

The issue you are describing is most likely caused by a JavaScript function that is being triggered when the store credit is applied or removed, which resets the agreements checkbox. To prevent this behavior, you can modify the JavaScript function to only reset the checkbox if it was not previously checked.

To do this, you will need to locate the JavaScript function that is causing the issue. You can try searching for it in your theme or module's JavaScript files or by using your browser's developer tools to inspect the JavaScript code that is being executed when the store credit is applied or removed.

Once you have located the function, you can modify it to include a check for the checkbox's previous state. Here is an example of how you can modify the function to achieve this:

```
    function applyStoreCredit() {
        // Code to apply store credit here

        // Check if agreements checkbox was previously checked
        var agreementsCheckbox = $('#agreement-checkbox');
        var agreementsWasChecked = agreementsCheckbox.prop('checked');

        // Code to remove store credit here

        // Only uncheck agreements checkbox if it was not previously checked
        if (!agreementsWasChecked) {
            agreementsCheckbox.prop('checked', false);
        }
    }
```

In this example, the function first checks the current state of the agreements checkbox and stores it in a variable called agreementsWasChecked. After removing the store credit, the function then checks the value of agreementsWasChecked to determine whether or not the checkbox should be unchecked.

By modifying the JavaScript function in this way, you should be able to prevent the agreements checkbox from being unchecked when adding or removing store credit.

Comment: I can't do that... the "Apply store credit" button, executes a submit, so the section page is reloaded, and after I get another checkbox input. I've updated my question.